# MSSQL Full Text search on binary field yields no results

Tags: sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I have a MS SQL database with a table that holds binary images of various documents (Word, Excel, PDF, etc).
I installed the Office Filters for FullTextSearch.

I ran:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'load_os_resources', 1
exec sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages';
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts'
```

The table in question has a content(Varbinary(MAX)) field with the actual binary content of the file and a mime type field.
I added a new column which evaluates the mime type and sets a proper document extension:

```
alter table core.DocumentObjectContent
add Extension as (case when contenttype = 'application/msword' then '.doc'
                              when contenttype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' then '.pptx'
                              when contenttype = 'application/pdf' then '.pdf'
                              when contenttype = 'application/vnd.ms-excel' then '.xls'
                              when contenttype = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint' then '.ppt'
                              when contenttype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' then '.xlsx'
                              when contenttype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' then '.docx' end)
```

I created the full text search catalog:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftCatalogY AS DEFAULT;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON core.DocumentObjectContent(content Type column extension) KEY INDEX PK_DocumentObjectContent ON ftCatalogY;
```

It built its index, but the index seems to be empty:

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_population
```

shows the FTS Index as "Starting". and a query on the sys.fulltextcatalogs table returns "Idle" status.

A simple select:

```
select * 
from core.DocumentObjectContent
where contains(content, 'a')
```

returns no results.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Drives me crazy :)

Comment: maybe stupid question, but did you actually import your documents into `DocumentObjectContent` table? What does `SELECT count(1) from core.DocumentObjectContent` return for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found what the issue was: The documents were saved archived as gzip and that is why the FTS wasn't working. Made a view over them using DECOMPRESS from SQL and based the FTS on that view. Works now.